# Swift - UIButton changes width

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

I am having a problem where a `UIButton` is changing`it's width if I add another`button`inside the same`view`.

This is how it looks without the 2nd `button`:

[image]

and this is how it looks if I constrain the 2nd button (title: "Wishlist?") inside the same `view`:

[image]

This is how I create the rounded image button:

```
let wishButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "wishButton"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    return v
}()

// constrain wishButton
    wishButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
    wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 72).isActive = true
    wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 72).isActive = true
```

2nd button with title:

```
let dropDownButton: dropDownBtn = {
    let v = dropDownBtn()
    v.setTitle("Wishlist?", for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

        // constrain dropDownButton
    dropDownButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dropDownButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: IDK how you center them X and Y and gives this look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicts

```
wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 72).isActive = true
wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 72).isActive = true
```

and

```
wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

You may mean

```
dropDownButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
dropDownButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```